# How to view as another country IP address?

Tags: ip

I need to view the Google music, but that is restricted in our country. Can I access it using any other fake IP address or how to view that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TOR](http://www.torproject.org/) and its [Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2275/).

To choose the country of exit node, read [this link](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/733/can-i-exit-from-a-specific-country-or-node).

Comment: You can't decide which country-ip you can get, that could still result in getting a banned country.

Answer (score 3):

Try the VPN providers [Hotspot Shield](http://hotspotshield.com/) or [HTTP-Tunnel](http://www.http-tunnel.com/html/).

As VPN-based solutions, in addition to changing your IP address they also encrypt your Web traffic, so that the local authorities cannot intercept it.

Both providers have free and paid accounts, where the paid ones are faster of course.

Answer (score 2):

[ProxyFire](http://www.proxyfire.net/) is a very small program which you can use to change your public IP address by using a number of free public proxies.

Answer (score 2):

You need a [proxy](http://www.olxads.com). You will not change your IP address, you will tell another computer to get the web page for you. You will not be able to chose you IP address, the computer sees, but you can chose the country. Web sites like http://www.samair.ru/proxy/ will give IP address of a proxy server. After you have the IP address you need to tell your web browser to use it. In IE click on tools Internet options then click on connections tab. Click on LAN settings. Check use a proxy server and enter the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Try [UltraSurf](http://www.ultrareach.com/). It's a speedy proxy that works like magic. With a one or two clicks you'll get a new IP address.

Comment: I believe the link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

[Spotflux](http://spotflux.com/) provides a managed and trusted connection to the internet that immediately reacts to and protects against emerging threats and unwanted tracking that affect mobile devices and desktop computers.

[Mediahint](https://mediahint.com/) is an extension for the Chrome & Firefox web browsers, that will anonymise your IP address (no configuration necessary).

[Hola Unblocker](http://hola.org/) is available for Android, Apple Mac, Windows as well as Chrome & Firefox extensions that will again anonymise your IP address.

Comment: hola does work like a charm